# Keras negative sampling with custom layer

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, sampling

I am trying to implement negative sampling in Keras. I wrote the following code that just compute the loss and I plan to add an additional output for the logits once I get it up and running. Here is the code:

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Masking, Layer
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow as tf


vocab_size = 20
n_features = 3
batch_size = 16
sequence_len = 10
embedding_size = 10

# Inputs
looked = Input((sequence_len,), dtype='int32', name='in_seq')
features = Input((sequence_len, n_features,), dtype='float', name='in_aux')
labels = Input((1,), dtype='int32', name='labels_')

looked_m = Masking(mask_value=0)(looked)
in_embed = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size, input_dim=vocab_size, input_length=sequence_len)(looked_m)

in_merged = Concatenate()([in_embed, features])

la_lstm = LSTM(256)(in_merged)
la_dense1 = Dense(128)(la_lstm)

loss = MyLayer(10, vocab_size, mode='train', name='my_layer')([la_dense1, labels])

model = Model(inputs=[looked, features, labels], outputs=[loss])
model.compile(loss=lambda loss, y_true: loss, optimizer='Adam')
```

Here is my custom layer

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_sampled, num_classes, mode, **kwargs):
        self.num_sampled = num_sampled
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.mode = mode
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        dense_shape, classes_shape = input_shape
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(self.num_classes, dense_shape[1]),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(name='bias',
                                      shape=(self.num_classes,),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)  # Maybe zero

        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, inputs_and_labels):
        inputs, labels = inputs_and_labels
        if self.mode == "train":
            loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                weights=self.kernel,
                biases=self.bias,
                labels=labels,
                inputs=inputs,
                num_sampled=self.num_sampled,
                num_classes=self.num_classes,
                num_true=1)

        elif self.mode == "eval":
            logits = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.transpose(self.kernel))
            logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, self.bias)
            labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, self.num_classes)
            loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                labels=labels_one_hot,
                logits=logits)

        return loss

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        dense_shape, classes_shape = input_shape
        return (dense_shape[0], )
```

Everything fine with dummy inputs

```
# Test
y = np.arange(batch_size)
y_one_hot = to_categorical(y, vocab_size)
x_looked = np.array([np.random.choice(np.arange(vocab_size),
                                          sequence_len,
                                          replace=True) for _ in range(batch_size)]
                        )
x_features = np.random.rand(batch_size, sequence_len, n_features)

layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict([x_looked, x_features, y])  # OK
```

But when I train

```
# Here comes the problem
model.fit([x_looked, x_features, y], y_one_hot)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-af27c0c040b8>", line 102, in <module>
    model.fit([x_looked, x_features, y], y_one_hot)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1689, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 990, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 440, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 80, in get_gradients
    raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I just flipped the arguments in the loss:

```
model.compile(loss=lambda loss, y_true: loss, optimizer='Adam')
```

should be

```
model.compile(loss=lambda y_true, loss: loss, optimizer='Adam')
```

Enjoy